# Having different versions of Python and Anaconda in same machine

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual, environment

I'm working and learning python with python 3.7 IDLE and PyCharm, but now I have to use Anaconda for a few different problems.

My question is, is it possible to install Anaconda in the same machine but without interfering the old python 3.7 that I already have installed? because in one I'm using Django as well and such, but Anaconda will be mainly for data processing, I and don't want them both to interact with each other or overwrite packages.

Shall I use something like a virtual environment to install Anaconda? if so, what's the best way.

I'm new into this, thank you for help!

Comment: What exactly do you want from Anaconda? What is your OS?

Comment: @DevonOliver I don't think it is a duplicate, if OP has to use the Anaconda distribution, then using virtualenv will be less appropriate than using conda to manage virtual environments.

Comment: thank you for the help and info : )

Comment: According to the following solution, you can retain existing Python installation and packages and just create a new virtual environment for Anaconda related stuff via Miniconda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853356/1047213

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anaconda comes with its own virtual environment manager `conda`. This means that Anaconda will by default be independent of your system python 3.7, and packages will not interact with each other.

One solution to manage both python installs in a clean way could be to use `conda` environments for both. The cleanest IMO would be to:

- install [Miniconda](https://conda.io/en/master/miniconda.html) (minimal install for the [`conda` manager](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/glossary.html#conda-glossary))
- create an environment called `anaconda` and install all packages from the distribution (which is done with `conda create -n anaconda anaconda`)
- create an environment called `py37` and install all packages from you current python 3.7 install

You can then use `conda activate py37` to use django, and `conda activate anaconda` to process data. No interaction between the two, and a very simple way to switch between both. Please see [the conda documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html) for details.

Of course, using virtualenv or pipenv would allow you to separate environments in a similar manner. But note that only conda will allow you to do so using features from the Anaconda distribution, which looks to be a requirement from your question.

Comment: You might need to be careful about your path, to be sure you were getting the python from conda on all occassions, and not the already installed non-conda install of python. Aside from that, I agree with this answer.

Comment: thank you for the help and info : )

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you using a virtual env for every project.

Here's a pretty informative video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk

And the venv docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: thank you for the help and info : )